# Can reflexology diagnose and cure disease?

Tags: medical-science, natural-remedies

I can find numerous references that reflexology is no better than placebo for particular medical conditions.

- [Quack Watch](http://www.quackwatch.com/01QuackeryRelatedTopics/reflex.html)
- [Evaluation of the effects of reflexology on quality of life and symptomatic relief in multiple sclerosis patients with moderate to severe disability](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23405024)

I am trying to take an objective view here. Is there any scientific evidence to support reflexology?

Comment: I significantly edited this question, because originally it only asked for evidence in one direction, and it asked for unevaluated evidence. Asking us to reproduce potentially unscientific claims isn't really consistent with our goals. You may get better results if you specify the condition that reflexology is treating. As the MS example shows, it is more likely that its effectiveness is studied on one condition at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't cure or diagnose diseases. However, it may relieve symptoms only in some situations.

> Reflexology is an increasingly popular complementary therapy in which parts of the body are deemed to be represented on the soles of the feet. The aim of this study was to investigate whether this representation can be used as a valid method of diagnosis. ... Despite certain limitations to the data provided by this study, the results do not suggest that reflexology techniques are a valid method of diagnosis.

***Source:*** White AR, Williamson J, Hart A, Ernst E. [*A blinded investigation into the accuracy of reflexology charts.*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11068346) Complement Ther Med. 2000 Sep;8(3):166-72.

> There is no evidence for any specific effect of reflexology in any conditions, with the exception of urinary symptoms associated with multiple sclerosis. Routine provision of reflexology is therefore not recommended.

***Source:*** Wang MY, Tsai PS, Lee PH, Chang WY, Yang CM. [*The efficacy of reflexology: systematic review.*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18489444) J Adv Nurs. 2008 Jun;62(5):512-20. doi: 10.1111/j.1365-2648.2008.04606.x.

> The purpose of this study was to evaluate the effectiveness of foot reflexology on fatigue, sleep and pain. ... Foot reflexology had a larger effect on fatigue and sleep and a smaller effect on pain. ... This meta-analysis indicates that foot reflexology is a useful nursing intervention to relieve fatigue and to promote sleep. Further studies are needed to evaluate the effects of foot reflexology on outcome variables other than fatigue, sleep and pain.

***Source:*** Lee J, Han M, Chung Y, Kim J, Choi J. *[Effects of foot reflexology on fatigue, sleep and pain: a systematic review and meta-analysis.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22310867)* J Korean Acad Nurs. 2011 Dec;41(6):821-33. doi: 10.4040/jkan.2011.41.6.821.

Comment: So, foot reflexology improves urinary symptoms associated with MS?

Comment: And apparently a good foot massage will help you get a good night's rest/help with fatigue.

Comment: Based on the listed results, it looks like it's the same drill as with any other form of placebo. It can prevent you from noticing some degree of pain or nausea, and may have some mild effect on inflammation, but can't actually heal anything.

Comment: What about the more recent systematic review from 2009 (Edzard Ernst: [Is reflexology an effective intervention? A systematic review of randomised controlled trials](https://www.mja.com.au/system/files/issues/191_05_070909/ern10490_fm.pdf))? It concludes: "The best evidence available to date does not demonstrate convincingly that reflexology is an effective treatment for any medical condition." That contradicts the claim that reflexology improves urinary symptoms.

Comment: Or [the update, from 2011](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378512210003890), which concludes: "It is concluded that the best clinical evidence does not demonstrate convincingly reflexology to be an effective treatment for any medical condition."

Comment: @Articuno: Sounds like enough for a competing answer if you are motivated.

Comment: @odd I agree, but thought that perhaps Cornelius had omitted these for some legitimate reason. If I don't hear back, ill write up an answer using these refs

Comment: @Articuno please do, it would be good to get all the information